# Lead resistance of 3 wire RTD100

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, resistance, temperature, wheatstone-bridge

I am using a three wire RTD100 as a temperature sensor.

[image]

I know the advantage of the 3 wire RTD100 is that it gives accurate temperature output by canceling the lead resistance. First the resistance between line RED (R1) and BLACK (R2) is measured the total resistance is R1 + R2 + RE and then the resistance between line BLACK (R2) and BLACK(R3) is measured. All three wires have the same resistance i.e R1=R2=R3 therefore we will have to subtract (R2+R3) from (R1 + R2 + RE) to get an accurate temperature value.

I researched about the circuits that I can use with 3 wire RTD100. A Wheatstone bridge is used to find the resistance change in the RTD100.

Circuit 1:

[image]

In the above circuit, the wire resistance of the RTD100 is labelled as RW1, RW2, RW3. I understand that the change in resistance will unbalance the Wheatstone bridge.  The output nodes of the Wheatstone bridge are given to the difference amplifier where we get the voltage output corresponding to the change in temperature, but I am not understanding how the Wheatstone bridge and the difference amplifier is canceling the lead resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>**Important Note**- the above circuit is only applicable when all the resistances are nominally at the same value i.e. the same magnitude balance current flows into both R1 and R2. I'm mentioning this because if the left half of the bridge has a different impedance to the right half, 3-wire connections to an external device don't produce wire-resistance cancellation correctly. In other words, at balance, R3 must equal R4.</sub>

So, I've added a label in red (inside a red circle) called "C". This is the "new lower power feed point" and you can now ignore the old node in black called "C": -

[image]

Can you see that R3 is in series with RW2 and equally, R4 is in series with RW1 and hence the balance is maintained? No? Read below: -

Consider that in balance, R3 equals R4 and R1 equals R2. This produces 0 volts output between "a" and "b". If R3 and R4 both increased by 10%, the bridge would still be in balance. And increasing both by 10% is the same as adding series resistance to them both. That series resistance comes from the interconnecting wires (RW1 and RW2) and, it can be presumed to be identical for both. So the bridge remains in balance no matter what value RW1 and RW2 is providing that they are both the same value.

RW3 is a red-herring because it doesn't imbalance anything when its value changes; it just affects the "gain" of the circuit.

Comment: but how lead resistance is cancelled ?@Andy aka

Comment: I've added some more information.

Comment: i have read about 3 wire rtd  that it is used to cancel the lead resistance like if the third wire only affects the gain of circuit so is it better if i use a 2 wire RTD as the gain will not be affected?@Andy aka

Comment: No. With a 2 wire RTD both gain AND balance will be affected.

Comment: @Andy aka added a new circuit in that wire resistance is only added with RTD as the output voltage is taken from Point A and B,  then how the lead resistance is getting cancelled?

Comment: @BrianDrummond in circuit 2 how the lead resistance is getting cancelled as both the wire resistance is in series with RTD  unlike in the case of Circuit 1 where R3 is in series with RW2 and equally, R4 is in series with RW1

Comment: Note the bottom of the bridge is the junction of RW3 and R4 in Andy's circuit. Now R3 is really R3+RW2, and R4 is really R4 + RW1. So RW1 cancels RW2. Your new circuit is the same apart from references : R2+RW2 balance RTD + RW1.

Comment: in my question in circuit 2 how does it cancels the lead resistance i am not able to understand that as the output Voltage is taken from point A and B both the wire resistance is in series with RTD then how lead resistance is getting cancelled?@ BrianDrummond

Comment: Circuit 2 is the same as your original circuit. Just think about it and then remove it because it's clearly adding confusion to all parties because it uses different reference names for the bridge components.

Comment: Okay i will think about it, sorry for confusion

Comment: @Andyaka i realized my mistake in interpretation of circuit ,thanks for help

Comment: @Andyaka is there any thing i can do to minimize the effects of RW3 on gain

Comment: @powermachines the conventional way is to add a fourth wire from the red circled point marked "C" and measure that voltage and use it to compensate for the line attenuation. It's called ratiometric compensation (or words to that effect).

Comment: Compensate by increasing the excitation voltage by about RW3/R1, i.e. not very much.

Answer (score 0):

Wheatstone won't help here.

Two matched current sources, then \$ V_{dif}=I_1\cdot R_W + V_{rtd} - I_2\cdot R_W \$

I1=I2, Rw equal then

Vdif=Vrtd

A reference voltage for ADC is then Vref=(I1+I2)/Rref;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUUbku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>